# Select Controller Dynamically from SQL entry C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is perhaps a bizarre question.

I'm trying to create a mini CMS where an admin user will be able to dynamically create pages and decide what controllers should be used to render the page.

For example, a user may create a page called "News" in an admin control panel on the website and set the controller to "NewsController", down the road they may want to switch this to "BlogController".

My initial thought was to create an SQL table called Pages that would have the following columns (super simple at the moment): Path, Controller.

The path would be "/news" and the controller would be "NewsController".

If a user navigated to example.com/news, the system should check the SQL table for an entry where path = "/news" and pull the controller from there and MapRoute it properly, eventually returning the appropriate view for the selected controller.

In the past I've only set up controllers for pre existing CMSs where they seemingly do this in the backend.

Am I thinking of this correctly? Is there a better way to handle this? I haven't modified routes before, so I'm unsure if I'm even handling this correctly.

What I have so far is (code is in a very crude state right now!):

```
public class ControllerSelector
{
    public static string GetController()
    {
        //get site path
        string url = "/test";
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Solution\Project\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            string sql = @"SELECT Controller FROM Pages WHERE Path = @p";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = url;
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string controller = "Home";
            string action = "Index";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.GetValue(0) != null)
                {
                    controller = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                }
            }
            reader.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            return controller + "/" + action + "/";
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CMSRoute",
            url: ControllerSelector.GetController(),
            defaults: new {controller = "Page", action = "Display", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Edit:

I've updated my question with a clearer example, hopefully that helps!

The news idea was just an example, but largely all the pages have to be abstract in what controller they use.

In this case, most of the Controllers will be returning Modular views (views that will be marked up for use anywhere on a page, for any given page).

An admin of the site might decide to wire up a new landing page (Let's call it LandingPage) that has a news module, an events module and a gallery module. In the admin CP they would order these modules (keeping it simple for now) from first to last (i.e News, then Events, then Gallery).

This would add a table entry with Page = "/LandingPage" and Controller = "News,Events,Gallery" (for sake of explanation I added these all in one row, but wouldn't in practice haha!

When a page URL gets called (i.e: Example.com/LandingPage), it fetches the database entry where Page = /LandingPage and figures out the controllers it needs to call to then render the pages.

Down the line, the admin may decide they want to remove the News section from the Landing Page, they would remove this in the admin CP, save, update the database, and then the next time that page is visited, since the controllers have changed, the views rendered would be different.

From the admin making these changes, they're not dealing with the code at all allowing them to modify this on the fly at anytime.

Hope that clears things up!

Comment: So is the controller already there or are you going to create a controller dynamically?  I'm a little confused.

Comment: The controllers already exist in code, this is just to allow them to be swapped, added or removed from a page.

Comment: This seems like a bit of overkill.  Why don't use just pass a value back to the controller like /News/SomeValue and have the default NewsController and a method that checked the value and redirects you?  Maybe I'm a little bit off track of what you're asking though so correct me if I'm wrong.  You want the user to click a button that goes to /News always, and based on some setting options they've made, /News will direct them to different views?

Comment: Well, now that I look at the code this might be what you're doing lol.  Fill me in :)